# Error while authentication of a PostAsync() request

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, authorization, multipartform-data

I am trying to submit a multipart/form-data in C#.

I use the following code to add the authentication header:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();               

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "token value XYZ");
```

And I later use the following code to post the multipart form:

```
using (MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {

                    form.Add(new StringContent(options["name"]), "name");
                    form.Add(new StringContent(options["timeIdentifier"]), "timeIdentifier");
                    form.Add(new StringContent(options["timeFormat"]), "timeFormat");
                    var result = client.PostAsync(url, form).Result;
                    sd =await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                 }
```

But I get an authentication error while connecting to the server. Please suggest a remedy. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `Bearer` authentication scheme in the `Authorization` header.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "Bearer <token value XYZ>");
```